# What is the error in this code?My data is not inserting into sql server

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have checked my api through postman and its working but the error is in the jquery or ajax.

I have tried to find error but cant understand.Please Try to solve this problem.Thankyou so much

```
       $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#AddPatientReport").click(function () {
            alert("PatientReport Added Successfully");

            var DoctorId = $("#ReportDoctorId").val();
            var DoctorName = $("#ReportDoctorName").val();
            var PatientName = $("#ReportPatientName").val();
            var PatientId = $("#ReportPatientId").val();
            var PharmacyCategory1 = $("#ReportPharmacyCategory1").val();
            var Medicine1 = $("#ReportMedicine1").val();
            var PharmacyCategory2 = $("#ReportPharmacyCategory2").val();
            var Medicine2 = $("#ReportMedicine2").val();
            var AppointmentDate = $("#ReportPatientDate").val();
            var AppointmentTime = $("#ReportPatientTime").val();
            var PatientDescription = $("#ReportPatientDescription").val();

            $.ajax({

                url: '/home/addpatientreport',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    DoctorId: DoctorId,
                    DoctorName: DoctorName,
                    PatientName: PatientName,
                    PatientId: PatientId,
                    PharmacyCategory1: PharmacyCategory1,
                    Medicine1: Medicine1,
                    PharmacyCategory2: PharmacyCategory2,
                    Medicine2: Medicine2,
                    AppointmentDate: AppointmentDate,
                    AppointmentTime: AppointmentTime,
                    PatientDescription: PatientDescription
                },
                dataType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: your urls seems to be incomplete ? Also you need to use json parser to parse the request

Comment: there can be many reasons some of them related to server-side code. For example posted data not read correctly, validation may fail, missing data, not properly escaped before addiong to db all these reasons

Comment: Check Developer Console in Chrome browser to see if you have any client side error. Also show your Action method and `ViewModel` So that others can help further.